# Drop the values lower than 5 percentile and higher 95 percentile withing each group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some dataset with following columns: order_code, city, weight
How to keep inside dataset only the parcels with weight *5percentile*<**x**<*95percentile* for each city (*like window function in SQL over(partition by city)*)?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': ['LA', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'LA', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Tokyo', 'Hamburg', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Hamburg', 'Hamburg', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo'],
    'weight': [930,933,1577,1018,547,981,1672,598,995,1164,601,1429,1349,1000,618,539,880,1472]
    })
```

Comment: post a testable dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `city` and filter parcels whose weight is in limits of quantiles:

```
df.groupby('city').apply(lambda x: x[(x.weight > x.weight.quantile(0.05)) 
                                     & (x.weight < x.weight.quantile(0.95))]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
     city  weight
0   Berlin     933
1   Berlin     995
2   Berlin     618
3  Hamburg     981
4  Hamburg    1164
5  Hamburg     601
6  Hamburg    1429
7  Hamburg    1000
8    Tokyo     880
9    Tokyo    1472
```

Answer (score 0):

Using with for loop:

```
dflist = []

for f in df['city'].unique():
    df_city = df[df['city'] == str(f)]
    df_city = df_city[(df_city['weight'] > df_city.weight.quantile(0.05)) & (df_city['weight'] < df_city.weight.quantile(0.95))]   
    dflist.append(df_city)

dfe = pd.concat(dflist)
```

Comment: it becomes harder, when have a lot of cities - more than 500

Comment: Use with for loop I posted.

Comment: you can use a groupby rather than looping over unique values: `for city, df_city in df.groupby('city'):`

Comment: So biased assessment.